# Why does AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN act like AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I call `setAutoResizeMode` with `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` and `AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS`, then I get expected results described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#doLayout()) when I resize the window.

When I call it with `AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN`, then I get behavior exactly as if I specified `AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS`.

Why?

Here's the MCV example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class ScrollableJTable extends JPanel {
    public ScrollableJTable() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable table = new JTable(10, 10);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS); // vary the constant
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel = new ScrollableJTable();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_221

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

# compile && go
$ javac ScrollableJTable.java && java ScrollableJTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `JTable` auto-resize mode only applies when a single column changed its own size and not the entire table. As per [`JTable.doLayout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/8/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#doLayout()) javadoc:

> If the `resizingColumn` is not `null`, it is one of the columns in the table that has changed size rather than the table itself. In this case the auto-resize modes govern the way the extra (or deficit) space is distributed amongst the available columns.

You can see this behavior by setting the column manually with [`JTableHeader.setResizingColumn()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#setResizingColumn-javax.swing.table.TableColumn-) with following code, it will auto-resize the last column:

```
JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
TableColumn lastColumn = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(9);
header.setResizingColumn(lastColumn);
```

Not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior. It could be [bug JDK-4098154](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4098154). A clue that it's a bug is revealed in the [`setResizingColumn` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#setResizingColumn(javax.swing.table.TableColumn)):

> Application code will not use this method explicitly, it is used internally by the column sizing mechanism.

They could have just as easily (and accurately) wrote this:

> If the only way you can make *your* code work is to use this method then *our* code has a bug.

Comment: You are correct, IMO, in both cases. It has to be a bug. It should be able to detect the last column in the column model and do what I say. But since it's not a big deal, then I won't log a bug. I'll do as you say. Good job!

Comment: In my case, I have a table with 2 columns and JTableHeader.setResizingColumn() still resized column 0 but not equal in size to column 1. A possible workaround is to set individually the maxwidth of each TableColumn. int numChars=1;JTextField txtFld=new JTextField(numChars);table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth((int) txtFld.getPreferredSize().getWidth());

Answer (score 1):

Make the number of columns 5 (to make the behaviour more apparent) and then resize the frame larger.

In both cases the columns will resize equally.

Next try resizing an individual column.

In this case you will see the different behaviour when using `AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN` and `AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS`.

I would guess the answer to your question is that the resize mode is only applicable to individual column resizing, not resizing of the entire table.

Comment: When I change the code back to use `AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN` and modify `(10, 10)` to `(5, 5)`, then I don't see any change in resize behavior. Do you? Additionally, the docs refer to resizing the table, which I presume is under the control of the `JScrollPane`. I don't see why the `JTable` should care who's telling it to resize itself. Right? BTW, thanks for jumping on this. I admire your work.

Comment: @JeffHolt, You included the link to the `doLayout()` method in your question. I didn't think I needed to include/quote that link again. I was trying to simplify the API explanation to point out the "resize mode" only applies when you resize an individual column.

Comment: I didn't fully comprehend the "resize" column concept when I asked my question nor did I understand that the default column model doesn't do what it should do. I believe your answer has value and you got my vote.